# Send a token other than ETH with WalletConnect_dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, blockchain, ethereum, web3dart

I'm currently working a dapp with flutter and use wallet_connect_dart to connect to metamask and make transaction. But i can only send ETH, i want to send other tokens as well, like DAI. How to manipulate that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to send tokens other then ETH, you just have to create a deeplink for that token on 'https://metamask.github.io/metamask-deeplinks/#', but first you have to prompt user to add that token in metamask account.
keep in mind you cannot get transaction hash from this method.